# AngularJs Table not updated after Create/Delete/update

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-bootstrap

If I Create/Update/Delete Values in my Array the ng-table is not Updating the Data. I need to do a window.location.reload() for that but thats not very "beautifull". Shouldnt in Angularjs through 2Way DataBinding and Automatic $apply Cycle it do it by it self?
My Code to Review maybe I forgot something:

```
'use strict';
(function() {
  class TranslationsComponent {
    constructor($http, $scope, $uibModal) {
        this.$http = $http;
        this.$scope = $scope;
        this.$uibModal = $uibModal;
        this.langV = [];
      }
  $onInit() {// getting my Datas
        this.$http.get('/api/dict_keys/all/' + 1 + '/' + 1)
          .then(response => {
            this.langV = response.data;
          });

    }
    // For Example Deleting something with a Modal
    // Delete Modal
    deleteKey(selectedKey) {
        this.$uibModal.open({
          scope: this.$scope,
          templateUrl: 'delete.html',
          controller: ['$scope', '$uibModalInstance', '$http', 'selectedKey',
            function($scope, $uibModalInstance, $http) {
              $scope.selectedKey = selectedKey;
              this.$http = $http;
              $scope.close = function() {
                $uibModalInstance.dismiss();
              };
              $scope.delete = () => {
                this.$http.delete('/api/dict_keys/' + selectedKey._id)
                  .then(() => {
                    //window.location.reload();
                    //what can i instead of realod do?
                    toastr.success('The Key is successfully Deleted');
                    $uibModalInstance.close(); 
                  });
              };
            }
          ],
          resolve: {
            selectedKey: () => selectedKey
          }
        });
      } 
  /* ----------------------------------------- */
  angular.module('euconDictionaryApp')
    .component('translations', {
      templateUrl: 'app/translations/translations.html',
      controller: TranslationsComponent
    });
})();
```

In my .html its a Simple ng-repeat showing everything, in short:

```
    <tr dir-paginate="v in $ctrl.langV |itemsPerPage: 10">
              <td>
               {{v.Name}}
              </td>
  <td>
            <!-- Delete Key Button -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="$ctrl.deleteKey(v)">
            </button>
          </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you will need to update 'this.langV' array after delete or update in order to see the update. You can use javascript splice method to remove an item from array.

After delete you can use

```
this.langV.splice(this.langV.indexOf(v), 1)
```

After update you can update the item like

```
this.langV[index] = updateItem
```

Comment: this.langV is undefined in the Modal...
Using Ui-Bootstrap Modals

Comment: You'll need to wire up the close event to return the new values to the Controller, and then repopulate the `langV` property with the new values

Comment: deleteKey(selectedKey) { var _this = this; ....
Please store top level object some thing like this and u can access _this.langV

Comment: wow thx the Solution with _this solved it and much other Problems i have now I think. Never saw that in their Docs. So your answer is accepted.